# Should tag badges have a higher value when sorting on class?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, tag-badges

When you have a decent amount of gold/silver badges, silver/bronze tag badges might not be visible on your profile when you sort by class.

My own SO profile is an example of this situation; I currently have 4G 8S 31S, but a visitor will see trivial silver badges like [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1974/constituent) and [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty) rather than my [python](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/267/python) badge, which I think is unfortunate.

Could and should this be improved, perhaps by changing the value of tag badges?

**Note**: Tag-badges already have a fractionally increased sort value, as they appear before other badges of the same color. I was thinking more of bumping them up an entire level or more.

Answer (score 4):

When you sort by class, you sort by class ("metal")–silver is "higher" than bronze.

How is a bronze Python badge "higher" in value than a silver anything-else badge?

Special-casing tag badges isn't a valuable ROI. Tag badges already stand out (*I* can see your Python badge) by nature of their different color, and I don't see how it's any more "valuable" than a silver badge other than you'd prefer people know you have a bronze Python badge.

The current ordering is fine. It sounds more to me like you want to *de*-value some silver badges.

Comment: Tag badges are more specific than the generic badges, they show *what* a user is good at, instead of just saying the user did *something* good. This seems a good enough reason to me to want to showcase them more than the others.
And sort by class is already biased towards tag badges. Currently, weights are like: bronze 1, silver 2, gold 3. Tag badge: Add +0.1. I'm just suggesting to increase that to 1 or even 2 to increase visibility.

Comment: @Junuxx And I'm saying I disagree, because I don't believe a bronze tag badge is with more than a generic silver badge.

Comment: (@Junuxx "Worth more", darn autocomplete.)